# Not able to run anything after Flask app run

Tags: python, flask

Here is the Flask code that I am trying to run:

```
import threading
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def index():
    df = pd.read_csv('data').drop('Open', axis=1)
    chart_data = df.to_dict(orient='records')
    chart_data = json.dumps(chart_data, indent=2)
    data = {'chart_data': chart_data}
    return render_template("index.html", data=data)
app.run(host="0.0.0.0",port=2000,debug=True)
```

The above code ran without error, so I included my tensorflow after that. But nothing works after the `app.run()`.

```
import threading
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def index():
    df = pd.read_csv('data').drop('Open', axis=1)
    chart_data = df.to_dict(orient='records')
    chart_data = json.dumps(chart_data, indent=2)
    data = {'chart_data': chart_data}
    return render_template("index.html", data=data)
app.run(host="0.0.0.0",port=2000,debug=True)
import tensorflow as tf
print("Tensorflow version: ",tf.__version__)
```

I tried running the app in separate thread but it is not working at all.

```
threading.Thread(app.run(host="0.0.0.0",port=2000,debug=True)).start()
```

Please advise me how I can run the code that is after app.run().
**EDITED:**
After the suggest from
I tried this:

```
import threading
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/result")
def index():
    df = pd.read_csv('data').drop('Open', axis=1)
    chart_data = df.to_dict(orient='records')
    chart_data = json.dumps(chart_data, indent=2)
    data = {'chart_data': chart_data}
    return render_template("index.html", data=data)
app.run(host="0.0.0.0",port=2000,debug=True)
@app.route("/")
import tensorflow as tf
```

And I got the following error:

```
    import tensorflow as tf
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `app.run` is a blocking call... What are you expecting to happen and why?

Comment: In particular, your tensorflow code is not in a route. You won't be able access it remotely anyway... Why does it matter where you place those lines?

Comment: I have explained what I am trying to achieve. I just want to run and print the tensorflow version. But in the similar fashion or if there is any other means.

Comment: But why after flask starts?

Comment: For example,  add a `@app.route("/tf-version")`, and it'd work fine

Comment: I am trying to run the training and want to display the output after that using the flask template. But I cannot give the whole code here. So I just tried to explain my scenario. If I am able to print the statement then I can do anything , right? I have tried using Matplotlib but there are certain restrictions I am facing which could be remove using the HTML Templates.

Comment: @cricket_007 Where I can add please can you tell me? I have tried that but it is not working and giving error.

Comment: I would suggest using Dash, not matplotlib for html https://dash.plot.ly/integrating-dash

Comment: If you have an error, edit the question with the code that generates it

Comment: I guess the issue will remain the same, even after using dash. I have issue running the app itself then how is ot possible that dash will allow it.

Comment: @cricket_007 ok editing the question

Comment: I think your error is that `pd` is never defined and you never import json

Comment: @cricket_007 No as per your suggestion I tried including it in the route.

Comment: Seems like you might want to go over a Flask guide? You cannot add a route to just anything. Needs to be a function, not an import statement

Comment: @JafferWilson Check out my reply below, I give approaches to achieve what you intend to do.

Comment: @JafferWilson Please clarify what you want to accomplish, using plain language instead of code. As your question stands now it is not at all clear what this should accomplish.

Comment: @a_guest I have already explained what I am trying to achieve and its all in the question. What else you want to know. I just want that the latter part of the code should run and it should not get stuck up. Thats it. Currently, my code get stuck up.

Comment: @JafferWilson You explained what you tried and how it didn't work. It would be good if you could describe what you want to accomplish on a higher level. What's the purpose of importing tensorflow and printing the version? Who will read that output? It's hard to make sense of your example as it stands. Right now you explained your goal implementation specific: *execute code after `app.run()`*. As has been notes many times in the comments this is not possible since `app.run()` is a blocking call. Hence we need to know what you want to achieve, not what you want to implement.

Answer (score 2):

Flask's `app.run(..)` is blocking.
If you want to use Tensorflow import it prior to starting the server and call logic within a route.

## Edit after comments

> I am trying to run the training and want to display the output after that using the flask template.

### Option 1

Sounds like you're trying to do something similar to Tensorboard. Do you know about this? https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/get_started

### Option 2

Otherwise, perform the training prior to `app.run(...)`. The downside is that server will not start until training is done (which may be fine).

### Option 3

- Move your training logic to a separate python file, have the training export results to a text file.
- In your server file, write a route to load this file, parse it and fill
  your template with the data from it.

This approach is super easy to setup (no messing with Threading or Process), just run each file in a different console.

(Please take note this is pretty much what Tensorboard does, it just does it in a much more advanced fashion)

Comment: Yes, similar to tensorboard. But the issues with tensorboard are not letting me display the content as I want it. They have there way to display which I cannot understand. Hence, I am trying my way.

Comment: @JafferWilson Tensorboard is an hefty piece of software, it takes quite some time and experience to get it to do what you want to achieve with it. And you need some good practice with Tensorflow first. But in the long run, it's a good investment to practice with it, because you're probably more interested in training your own models instead of spending energy re-developping Tensorflow tooling

Comment: I have hands on experience with Tensorboard. I did not find it useful. Can you tell me is it possible with Tensorboard to display bars similar to this: https://bl.ocks.org/bricedev/0d95074b6d83a77dc3ad or even the japanese candle stick pattern or box plot, etc? I don't think it is doable with Tensorboard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209770/discussion-between-overdrivr-and-jaffer-wilson).

Answer (score 1):

Simply print before starting the server.

You'll have to import tensorflow before you use it anyway, so move imports to the top, too

```
import json 
from flask import Flask, render_template
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd 

app = Flask(__name__)
... 
print("Tensorflow version: ",tf.__version__)

app.run(host="0.0.0.0",port=2000,debug=True)
```

However, makes more sense as a route

```
@app.route('/tf-version') 
def tf_version():
    return tf.__version__
```